# Unresolved reference to function in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following `onCreate` function in my MainActivity.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var selected_answer = 0

    val btn_list = mutableListOf<ToggleButton>(button1, button2, button3, button4)

    for(i in btn_list){
        i.setOnClickListener{
            toggle_rest(btn_list.indexOf(i), btn_list)
            selected_answer = btn_list.indexOf(i)+1

        }
    }


    fun toggle_rest(toCheck : Int, btn_list : List<ToggleButton>){


        for (i in btn_list) {
            i.setChecked(btn_list.indexOf(i) == toCheck)

        }
    }
    question_txt.setText("Quiz will begin shortly!")
}
```

When I call `toggle_rest` it gives an error `toggle_rest:Unresolved reference`.

Comment: You have to declare the `fun` before you use. Put it higher in your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must Kotlin Local Functions be Declared Before Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511633/must-kotlin-local-functions-be-declared-before-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define `toggle_rest` function before you use in your code, otherwise you will get **unresolve reference** compile error:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var selected_answer = 0

    //Declare your function before you use
    fun toggle_rest(toCheck : Int, btn_list : List<ToggleButton>){
        for (i in btn_list) {
            i.setChecked(btn_list.indexOf(i) == toCheck)
        }
    }

    val btn_list = mutableListOf<ToggleButton>(button1, button2, button3, button4)

    for(i in btn_list){
        i.setOnClickListener{
            toggle_rest(btn_list.indexOf(i), btn_list)
            selected_answer = btn_list.indexOf(i)+1
        }
    }

    question_txt.setText("Quiz will begin shortly!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define function outside the onCreate() method, like below.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var selected_answer = 0

    val btn_list = mutableListOf<ToggleButton>(button1, button2, button3, button4)

    for(i in btn_list){
        i.setOnClickListener{
            toggle_rest(btn_list.indexOf(i), btn_list)
            selected_answer = btn_list.indexOf(i)+1

        }
    }
    question_txt.setText("Quiz will begin shortly!")
}

fun toggle_rest(toCheck : Int, btn_list : List<ToggleButton>){


    for (i in btn_list) {
        i.setChecked(btn_list.indexOf(i) == toCheck)

    }
}
```

Works as per your expectation.